# Direct limits of compact surfaces with uniformly bounded topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose we have a directed system of inclusions of compact surfaces with boundary
$$S_1 \hookrightarrow S_2 \hookrightarrow S_3 \cdots $$
such that all of the surfaces $\{S_k\}$ have *uniformly bounded topology*. That is, there exists some constant $C > 0$ independent of $k$ such that the genus and number of boundary components of $S_k$ is bounded above by $C$.

Then the surfaces have some well-defined direct limit surface $S$. I was wondering how pathological the topology of $S$ can become?

As of yet, I have been unable to produce any example that does not yield a punctured compact surface with finitely many punctures.

Venturing towards a possible proof of this statement, the uniform bound on the topology should imply via a quick Morse-theoretic argument that the surfaces $\{S_k\}$ become diffeomorphic for large $k$ and the inclusions are deformation retracts.

Comment: So long as the inclusion $f: S_k \hookrightarrow S_{k+1}$ has $f(\partial S_k) \cap \partial S_{k+1}$ a union of connected components of $\partial S_{k+1}$, all you do at each stage is glue on a cylinder, so you get exactly what you say. In general I imagine you can also cook up arbitrarily nasty punctures on the boundary; certainly the upper half plane is such a colimit, but I think so is the disc minus a Cantor set from the boundary.

Comment: How would you construct the disk minus a Cantor set? For me this looks like the infinite type surface that looks like an infinite binary tree, which seems to be impossible since we're never adding any boundary components for large $k$.

Comment: You have to be more careful about boundary components, or else what you say about deformation retracts is false. You can have an example where each odd surface $S_{2n+1}$ is a disc, each even surface $S_{2n}$ is an annulus, $S_{2n}$ is obtained from $S_{2n-1}$ by attaching a pair-of-pants (a 3-holed sphere) to the unique component of $\partial S_{2n-1}$, and $S_{2n+1}$ is obtained from $S_{2n}$ by attaching a disc to one component of $\partial S_{2n}$.

Comment: @Rohil Minus a Cantor set *on the boundary*. I can try to draw a picture of the suggestion tomorrow. Lee has pointed out a subtlety I missed above.

Comment: Does this picture clarify the idea? I have drawn all of the discs $S_i$ as topological submanifolds of the unit disc, each nested in the next. You can see how the portion of the boundary not contained in $S_i$ undergoes the middle-thirds construction of the Cantor set. https://photos.app.goo.gl/WEmkhNCQgeepSpYX7 I would be surprised if the answer was much different if you demanded smooth embeddings, though it would make those corners a little more irritating.

Comment: What is the topology on the union? One can construct an increasing sequence $(S_k)$ of surfaces, homeomorphic to the closed unit disk $\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|\le 1\}$, such that for any reasonable topology on the union $S=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$, the space $S$ is not locally compact at some point $x$ that belongs to the boundaries of all surfaces $S_n$. So, $S$ is not a surface.

Comment: @Mike Yes, this picture perfectly clarifies the idea, thanks!

Comment: @Taras We should assume that these embeddings are smooth - Mike's picture can be modified suitably so I think this is not restrictive at all.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I am interested to hear this construction.

Comment: @MikeMiller For every positive integer $n$ consider the disk $S_n=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z-n|\le n\}$ and observe that the union $S=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is not locally compact at zero.

Comment: Sorry to revive this already long comment thread, but here is a stipulation on the embeddings that removes all of the pathology displayed above. We require that, for all $i$, the embedding $S_i \hookrightarrow S_{i+1}$ sends $S_i$ to a compact subset of the _interior_ of $S_{i+1}$.